# ldapadd/ldapmodify: clarifications needed about these commands

Tags: ldap, ubuntu-10.04, openldap, ldif

The `ldapmodify` man page states that:

> The default for ldapmodify is to modify existing entries

Yet when I try to import an LDIF file with `ldapmodify` I get the below error:

```
ldapmodify: modify operation type is missing at line X
```

**Q1: Why, which arguments should I add to my ldapmodify command?**

If I import an LDIF file using `ldapadd` and the entry already exists I get the below error:

```
ldap_add: Already exists (68)
```

This can be ignored using the `-c` switch (for continue), however ldap_add won't update existing entries. Instead, in order to update existing entries one should use `ldapmodify`, however `ldapmodify` won't add missing entries.

**Q2: Is there a way to import an LDIF files by creating missing entries AND updating existing ones at the same time?**

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The ldif for ldapmodify has a different syntax than a regular ldif. 
For example: if you want to add the 'foo' entry with value 'bar' you should write your ldif like this:

```
dn: cn=ToModify,dc=example,dc=com
changetype: Modify
add: foo
foo: bar

replace: mail
mail: new@email.com

delete: unneededEntry
```

This ldif will add the attribute foo with value bar, update the mail attribute to new@email.com and delete the unneededEntry. 
then invoke the ldapmodify command.

```
ldapmodify -f update.ldif
```

(if needed with other options like simple auth for example)

Comment: Thanks. Are you able to comment on Q2 at all?

Comment: As far as I know this is not possible, therefore u have the 2 tools...
ldapmodify for existing entries, ldapadd to add new ones.

Comment: That's also the impression that I was getting. Since I don't have to preserve the existing LDAP content before doing the import, I'm going to purge LDAP with `ldapdelete` then import the LDIF with `slapadd`.

Answer (score 2):

Try the -a switch

```
Add or modify options:
  -a         add values (default is to replace)
```

Answer (score 1):

Goez answer seems fine.

However if you are unfamiliar with ldif it can make sense to use

```
ldapvi
```

instead. You can edit already existing entries or add new ones.

```
apt-get install ldapvi
```

Comment: Thanks but it doesn't scale up. For individual entry editing I'd much rather use something like this http://directory.apache.org/studio/.